# How to run multiple mongodb databases with same name on single mongodb instance?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, continuous-integration

We are trying to minimize CI pipeline resource usage by running multiple apps (dev branch deployments of the same app) on a single physical mongodb instance.

How can this be done best?

Currently each branch has its own physical mongodb instance.

The system has multiple logical databases for each single branch deployment.

Example of current state:

- Branch A -> programatically (node.js) spawns own mongodb with logical databases UserDb, EventDb, CarDb
- Branch B -> also spawns its mongodb with logical databases UserDb, EventDb, CarDb

Goal:

- single, shared mongodb instance
- Branch A -> logical databases UserDb, EventDb, CarDb running on the single mongodb instance
- Branch B -> same
- databases of Branch A and B are independent

Comment: Are you using kubernetes for CI ?

Comment: The best way of doing this will be to call the databases different names (like branch_b_UserDb, branch_b_EventDb, etc). Theoretically, you could run multiple `mongod` on different ports, but that's just sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian It's Gitlab CI which then deploys each new branch as a separate pod on kubernetes.

Comment: I am not very sure whether i understand the requirement or not. can we use namespace to handle this ? each branch will have its namespace. and each mongo can have same name and they are independent of each other

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanianThe requirement is to have a single mongodb server for all dev branches. Using k8s namespaces this cannot be solved as the underlying issue of name clashes inside mongodb remains. Thanks for your input in any case.

Comment: @willis Thanks for your input. Due to some misconfigs in our setup it was difficult to apply your approach. Fortunately, we found a way to refactor the existing codebase to allow external configuration. After that we can use the prefixing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The best way of doing this will be to call the databases different names (like branch_b_UserDb, branch_b_EventDb, etc).

by willis in [How to run multiple mongodb databases with same name on single mongodb instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120224/how-to-run-multiple-mongodb-databases-with-same-name-on-single-mongodb-instance?noredirect=1#comment98902849_56120224)